# Always show Clementine's controll buttons in indicator

Tags: unity, indicator-sound, clementine

When Rhythmbox is installed, it's control buttons are always shown in the sound indicator, even when the program isn't running.

Now I've removed it and installed Clementine instead. In the indicator it looks like Rhythmbox, except those control buttons (previous, play/pause, next). The are only there when Clementine is running. If not, there's only Clementine's entry.

Can I "fix" this somehow?

When running:

[image]

When not:

[image]